# python regular expressions match # ner

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the positions using regular expressions in a file like this:

```
 36 17.89 N,  2 51.62 W
 35 51.13 N,  2 51.62 W
 35 51.13 N,  2 49.14 W
 36 17.89 N,  2 49.14 W
 36 17.89 N,  2 46.66 W
 35 51.13 N,  2 46.66 W
 35 51.13 N,  2 44.18 W
 36 17.89 N,  2 44.18 W
 36 17.89 N,  2 41.7 W
 35 51.13 N,  2 41.7 W
 35 51.13 N,  2 39.22 W
 36 17.89 N,  2 39.22 W
 36 17.89 N,  2 36.74 W
 35 51.13 N,  2 36.74 W
 35 51.13 N,  2 34.26 W
 36 17.89 N,  2 34.26 W
```

It is a .txt file.

The regex for extract the data is :

```
pattern = r'((?m)^\t\s([1-9]?[0-9])\s([0-9]?[0-9]\.?[0-9]{0,2}))\s([NS]),\s{0,2}([1-9]?[0-9])\s([0-9]?[0-9]\.?[0-9]{0,2}).([WE])'
```

I can extract the groups to process strings to float but I want to know how can I store in a list the number of the match as a 'ID' of each line

for example `(3, 35.8521,-2.685666)`

in a list, a tuple or some iterable

Comment: You `enumerate()` through each line, and append a tuple like you suggest to a list inside that loop?

Answer (score 0):

I would use split instead of regex:

```
with open('coordinates.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        coord = [pair.split() for pair in line.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerate to get the index of each line, like so:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(
    r'(?m)^\s*([0-9]+)\s*([0-9.]+)\s*([NS]),\s*([[0-9]+)\s*([0-9.]+)\s*([WE])')
with open('in.txt') as f:
    result = [
        (i, lat, lng) for i, (lat, lng) in enumerate(
            ((int(lat) + float(latf) / 60) * (1 if latdir == 'N' else -1),
             (int(lng) + float(lngf) / 60) * (1 if lngdir == 'E' else -1))
            for lat, latf, latdir, lng, lngf, lngdir
            in pattern.findall(f.read()))]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Or, if you prefer each step in its own statement:

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    # Get the characters from the file
    data = f.read()

# Find the formatted fields
data = pattern.findall(data)

# Convert the string fields into numeric values
data = (((int(lat) + float(latf) / 60) * (1 if latdir == 'N' else -1),
     (int(lng) + float(lngf) / 60) * (1 if lngdir == 'E' else -1))
    for lat, latf, latdir, lng, lngf, lngdir in data)

# Add an index
data = enumerate(data)

# Flatten the tuple
data = ((i, lat, lng) for i, (lat, lng) in data)

# And there you are
result = list(data)
```

In either case, if you want 1-based indexes, use `(i+1, lat, lng) for i, ...`.

Comment: Great.  Simple but accurate